# error serving pdf in django 1.8

Tags: django, pdf

In django 1.8 I have a couple of functions that read pdf files and return them, and that generate a pdf with reportlab and return it.
In some cases the file is served correctly, but sometimes the PDF is opened by the browser as if it were html and what is even more strange, pdf source is displayed in my django base template. 
In this case, if reloading the page after the error, the pdf is served.

This is the code of a view:

```
fpdf = open (path, 'rb')
return HttpResponse (FileWrapper (fpdf), content_type = 'application/pdf')
```

and this is the code of the other:

```
pdf = pisa.CreatePDF (StringIO.StringIO (html.encode ("UTF-8")), result)
if not pdf.err:
    response = HttpResponse (result.getvalue (), content_type = 'application / pdf')
    response ['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename =% S.pdf '% (doc.name.replace ("", "_"))
    return response
    #Return HttpResponse (result.getvalue (), content_type = 'application/pdf')
```

Returning the PDF as an attachment is a test that I made to see if solved, because the desired behavior would be directly open the file.
Unfortunately, the error still occurs even so.

Comment: In the second example you have redundant spaces around slash: ```content_type = 'application / pdf'```

Comment: I discovered that there was a javascript that loaded the pdf via ajax and inserted the response in the page. After eliminating the javascript, the problem went away. I apologize for posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
response = HttpResponse (result.getvalue (), content_type = 'application / pdf')
```

To this line

```
response = HttpResponse (result.getvalue (), content_type = 'application/octet-stream')
```

This will make the file to be treated as a binary, and downloaded to the user instead of opening it in the browser.

If you view it inside the browser, follow  Igor Pomaranskiy advice, and remove the space inside your content_type variable by doing the following

Change this
    content_type = 'application / pdf'
to this

```
content_type = 'application/pdf'
```

Comment: `application/pdf` is perfectly valid (note the lack of spaces) and some browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc.) will display it in-line. But forcing the `application/octet-stream` content type will force-download it, which the OP explicitly mentions they don't want.

Comment: I thought OP wants to download the pdf, not viewing it inside the browser. He is viewing a contant that doesn't have a correct  content_type